# How to check urls againts a predefined list of regex rules in order to get a match in python?

Tags: python, regex, url, routes, matching

I'm trying to match url request that have literal components and variable components in their path to a list of predefined regex rules. Similar to the routes python library. I'm new to regex so if you could explain the anchors and control characters used in your regex solution I would really appreciate it.

assumming I have the following list of rules. components containing : are variables and can match any string value.

```
(rule 1) /user/delete/:key
(rule 2) /user/update/:key
(rule 3) /list/report/:year/:month/:day
(rule 4) /show/:categoryid/something/:key/reports
```

here are example test cases which show request urls and the rules they should match

```
/user/delete/222 -> matches rule 1
/user/update/222 -> matches rule 2
/user/update/222/bob -> does not match any rule defined
/user -> does not match any rule defined
/list/report/2004/11/2 -> matches rule 3
/show/44/something/222/reports -> matches rule 4
```

can someone help me write the regex rules for rule 1,2,3,4 ?

Thank you!!

Comment: sorry, I made an error editing the question. the details are back now

Comment: Oh, okay. Could you check out my answer? I hope this time I understood your requirements.

Comment: perfect! looks pretty simple too. if I wanted to match strings I guess it's [a-zA-z] ?

Comment: If you want to match only *letters*, then you can use `[a-zA-Z]` (be careful with the upper/lower case, they are important!). If you want to ignore cases (case insensitive matching), then you can use flags, for example with `re.match`, you'd use something like `re.match(r'[a-z]+', theString, re.IGNORECASE)` (the `re.IGNORECASE` at the end indicate case insensitivity and will allow a match of both `a` and `A` for example.).

Comment: perfect thx! one last question, for alphanumeric I should use [:alnum:] ?

Comment: If you are not sure, use `[a-z0-9]`. Python doesn't support the syntax of `[:alnum:]`, but you could use `\w`, which will match alphanumeric and underscore. That one could be said to be the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a regex to do something like that. You can split and count:

```
if len(url.split("/")) == 4:
    # do something
```

You make sure the length is 4 because there's an additional element at the beginning which is an empty string.

Of using something like:

```
if url.count("/") == 3:
    # do something
```

If you really want to use regex, them maybe you could use something like this:

```
if re.match(r'^(?:/[^/]*){3}$', url):
    # do something
```

---

As per your edit:

You could use this for rule 1:

```
^/user/delete/[0-9]+$
```

For rule 2:

```
^/user/update/[0-9]+$
```

For rule 3:

```
^/list/report/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}$
```

For rule 4:

```
^/show/[0-9]+/something/[0-9]+/reports$
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string. `$` matches the end of the string. Together, they make sure that the string you are testing begins and ends with the regex; there's nothing before or after the 'template'.

`[0-9]` matches any 1 digit.

`+` is a quantifier. It will allow for the repetition of the character or group just before it. `[0-9]+` thus means 1 or more digits.

`{4}` is a fixed quantifier. It is a bit like `+`, but it repeats only 4 times. `{1,2}` is a variation of it, it means between 1 and 2 times.

All the other characters in the regex above are literal characters and will match themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can specify that you want only three matches as follows:

`'^((\/(\w+)){3})$'` with the g and m flags enabled

`^` matches from start of string
`(\/(\w+)){3}` matches (a forward slash followed by alphanumeric characters) exactly 3 times
`$` matches end of string

`g` flag to return more than just one match
`m` flag to make the `^` and `$` treat each line of text as a separate string rather than just one huge multi-line string.

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/xT3xW2

I will assume `my_str` is a string that is valid by the regex above
Then, to make a method call with that, you can do:

```
eval(my_str.split('/')[1]+my_str.split('/')[2].capitalize()+'('+my_str.split('/')[3]+')')
```

Here is what the above string within eval returns:

```
>>> print my_str.split('/')[1]+my_str.split('/')[2].capitalize()+'('+my_str.split('/')[3]+')'
userUpdate(222)
```

OR

```
userDelete(222)
```

Then you simply do `eval()` on it to get the method call. That is the best I can do right now.

Comment: well I'm in the middle of writing a python dispatcher and would need to have different urls call different functions. For example, the url /user/update/222 and /list/reports/2004/11/2 would have to call different functions. I just need to understand how to recognize url that follow a certain pattern which are composed of literal and variable components.

Comment: @user1018567, Well that is what my answer above highlights. To work with different number of `'/'` just change the number in the `{}`. If you have any more questions, just ask.

Comment: very cool! since it's a dispatcher I need to have my urls call different functions.
/user/update/222 calls function userUpdate(222)
/user/delete/222 calls function userDelete(222)
how would you modify the regex to take into account the literal parts?

Comment: @user1018567, Ah I see. I'll update my answer. Please wait a minute

Comment: @user1018567, I updated my answer. It works but sorry, I have to go now. If my answer was helpful, would you mind [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it? Thank you and good luck

Comment: ok I see what you did. I'm not really concerned about calling the function and transforming the url into a function call. I just want to match the url against a list of prebuilt regexes that I defined in a list. Once I get a match, then I can do what I want, (ie call a method, print something, etc). so how would you handle the regex matching if I had a list of regexes predefined?